# Deadlock in transaction of Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, deadlock, sql-server-2014

I have a small program and which makes use of Entity Framework. I used them in below way.

1. Create procedures in database.
2. Make a transaction in entity framework.
3. Call the procedures in that transaction.

That's cannot be more simple. However, I suspected whether it is possible of deadlock? My code lists below.

```
void AddA()
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            db.Add_A("helloA");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            db.Add_B("helloB");
            tran.Commit();
        }
    } 
}

void AddB()
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            db.Add_B("helloB");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            db.Add_A("helloA");
            tran.Commit();
        }
    } 
}
```

`Add_A` and `Add_B` are procedures here.

From my perspective, the two methods will cause dead lock when called at the same time since they occupy the tables in different order.

However, when I do some tests, the dead lock didn't happen. What is wrong here? Did I do something wrong or there is no risk of dead lock?

Any feedback is welcome. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using SQL Server 2014 and Entity Framework 6.0.

Comment: How do you call AddA and AddB? Because if it's just sequential, you'll never conflict

Comment: Why are you using transactions at all? `SaveChanges` already uses a transaction. If you save at each of the `Add` methods, you are doing it wrong. You should add all the entities you need to the context, then call SaveChanges once

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Well, I called AddA and AddB at the same time, from what I know, that may has problems since AddA occupies table A first while AddB occupies table B first and they long to occupy the other table already occupied by each other.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Well, I called AddA and AddB at the same time, from what I know, that may has problems since AddA occupies table A first while AddB occupies table B first and they long to occupy the other table already occupied by each other.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your help. But why I used procedure here is there are some logic in procedure. So, after all what I want achieve is to create a transaction which contains multiple procedures and not occur any deadlock. I am a little silly on database stuffs so I know it is not a good way. Do you have a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question what the procedures are doing. The deadlock will only happen if both Add_A and Add_B contains statement that place a lock that is not compatible if called more than once.

For example if both Add_A and Add_B simply run a select statement (under default isolation level read committed), then no deadlock will occur because select statement only put a shared lock that is compatible with another shared lock placed by other thread. If Add_A and Add_B contains update statement then the deadlock will occur (when you run both at the same time or different time but less than the delay), because update statement will put an exclusive lock to an object which is incompatible with another exclusive lock.